# What is a common idiom for converting between Integral types?

Tags: haskell, integer

I want to convert between various integral types; for example Word32 and Word8.

What is the idiomatic way to do this in Haskell?

Word8 -> Word32 conversion can always succeed. Word32 -> Word8 conversion might result in an overflow and I'll deal with that (either by testing explicitly or getting an indication from whatever the conversion idiom is).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301523/haskell-error-couldnt-match-expected-type-integer-against-inferred-type-int

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`fromIntegral` will convert from an integral type to any numeric type, including other integral types

Answer (score 3):

See [Converting Numbers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers) in the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/)