# Converting Int to Integer

Tags: haskell, integer, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell Error: Couldn't match expected type `Integer&#39; against inferred type`Int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301523/haskell-error-couldnt-match-expected-type-integer-against-inferred-type-int)

How can I convert `Int` to `Integer` in Haskell?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301523/haskell-error-couldnt-match-expected-type-integer-against-inferred-type-int

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There is a [`toInteger`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v%3atoInteger)  function you can use.

Answer (score 18):

fromIntegral is a good generic way to convert any Integral value into any other Integeral. But as sth said, toInteger works for the case of converting specifically to an Integer.

Answer (score 5):

also, you can use `fromIntegral` (since `Int` is an `Integral`)